# How to separate from 1 column to multiple columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and I need to separate the data to multiple columns:

```
 "Site Name","PJ.143 USJ 1| 2A (MP)","PMAC ID:","0067","Channel No:","01"
```

How to separate from 1 column to multiple columns in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: *Don't* store values like this in the first place. This is breaking 1st Normal Form and creating a lot of problems, eg, it's impossible to index such a column, or update it.

Comment: please share the expected output as well

Comment: You can use the [STRING_SPLIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) function in SQL Server 2016 and later.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Also check [Aaron Bertrand's articles](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split) on string splitting before 2016. The fastest option is to use SQLCLR. Second best, using XML tricks, is [almost twice as slow](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) but doesn't require SQLCLR

Comment: The expected output from other table which is:                                     COL 1 :  PJ.143 USJ 1| 2A (MP)   COL2 :   0067 and  last  COL 3 =   01

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not require a Split/Parse UDF

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeColumn varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'"Site Name","PJ.143 USJ 1| 2A (MP)","PMAC ID:","0067","Channel No:","01"')

Select A.ID
      ,Col1 = max(case when RetSeq=2 then RetVal end)
      ,Col2 = max(case when RetSeq=4 then RetVal end)
      ,Col3 = max(case when RetSeq=6 then RetVal end)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                        ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.SomeColumn,'"',''),',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
              ) B      
 Group By A.ID
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Col1                    Col2    Col3
1   PJ.143 USJ 1| 2A (MP)   0067    01
```

Comment: @mohdnizam Happy it helped.